# Import into python interpreter main namespace from an import

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I run a bunch of imports and path appends from the interpreter with one command/import? If I import another module that runs the commands for me the imports are not available in main namespace. Similar to running a bash script that modifies/adds commands and variables to the current session.

ex.

```
import os, ...
sys.path.append(...)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the names from that module into your main namespace? That's just `from foo import *` instead of `import foo`. Or are you asking how to make the module itself reach outward and force modules onto you? Or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're just looking for the `from … import …` statement. For example:

lotsostuff.py:

```
import json
def foo(): pass
```

Now:

```
$ python3.3
>>> from lotsostuff import *
>>> json
<module 'json' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py'>
>>> foo
<function lotsostuff.foo>
```

---

However, you might want to consider a different alternative. If you're just trying to control the startup of your interpreter session, you can do this:

```
$ PYTHONSTARTUP=lotsostuff.py
$ python3.3
>>> json
<module 'json' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py'>
>>> foo
<function __main__.foo>
```

Notice the difference in the last line. You're now running `lotsostuff` in the `__main__` namespace, rather than running in a separate namespace and grabbing all of its members.

---

Similarly:

```
$ python3.3 -i lotsostuff.py
>>> json
<module 'json' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py'>
```

You'd normally use `PYTHONSTARTUP` if you want to do this every time in your session, `-i` if you want to do it just this once.

---

If you want to do the same thing in the middle of a session instead of at startup… well, you can't do it directly, but you can come pretty close with [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) (Python 3.x) (or [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) in Python 2.x).

---

If you really want to do *exactly* what you described—importing a module, as a normal import, except merged into your namespace instead of in its own—you'll need to customize the import process. This isn't that hard with [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html); if you're not in Python 3.2 or later, you'll have a lot more work to do it with [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html).

---

That's pretty much the difference between `. ./foo` instead of just `./foo` in a `bash` script that I think you were looking for.

If you're using [`ipython`](http://ipython.org), there are even cooler options. (And if you're not using `ipython`, you might want to check it out.)

Comment: Thanks! The -i flag was just what I was looking for.